# What values are defined for the SpecialAccounts/UserList key and what I is their purpose?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry

I have an old program from 2010 which uses the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList key. You can add DWORD values under that key. The program works on Windows Xp (5.1). Now my question is: What values are possible DWORD values for that value and which purpose do they have?

Comment: The program uses the value of 65536.

Comment: The correct key is  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList. The "CurrentVersion" part is currently missing above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is old, but it might help someone: experimentation on Windows XP has shown me that the DWORD value 65536 tells to winlogon to hide all the user accounts *starting* with the value name.

For example, having the name "IUSR_" with the DWORD value 65536 in the UserList registry key will hide the user "IUSR_MACHINENAME".  If the DWORD value is 0 the user won't match and will thus be available in the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

There are three possible DWORD values in total:
The value of 0 hides the user account from the welcome screen. However the user account is still visible under the control panel. The value of 1 shows the user on the welcome screen.
The last possible values is 65536 (0x10000). That value hides the user account as well from the welcome screen as well as from the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

The accounts listed at this location in the registry are hidden from the Windows home/logon screen.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But what values are possible DWORD values for an entry under that key?

Comment: there is example use of it here http://charlesgallery.blogspot.com/p/computer-hidden-tricks.html . Better example here http://www.top-password.com/blog/hide-user-account-from-welcome-screen-in-windows-8-7-vista-xp/

Comment: Yes but these examples don'texplain what meaning a value of 65536 has. And my program used the value of 65536.